# In any finite graph with at least two vertices, there must be two vertices with the same degree

Tags: graph-theory

Show that, in any finite graph with at least two vertices, there must be two vertices with the same degree.

***HINTS ONLY!***

Answer (score 16):

Hint: Suppose the graph has $n$ vertices.  Which integers can be the degree of a vertex?

Comment: 0 to n-1 possible for degrees?

Comment: @MathyPerson Right, but you can't have both $0$ and $n-1$.

Comment: @CareBear ah i see! then we can use pigeonhole?

Comment: @MathyPerson Yes, this is what Seth is hinting at.

Comment: The range of the degree of these vertices can either be $[0,1,2,...,n-2]$ or $[1,2,3,...,n-1]$, which is important, because it indicates there are $n-1$ holes with $n$ pigeaons ($n$ vertices).

Answer (score 5):

Degree of a vertex can range from $1$ to $n-1$ and the number of vertices is $n$. Hence according to the pigeon hole principle at least $2$ vertices will have the same degree.

Comment: This is not quite correct: a vertex can also have degree $0$, so there are in fact $n$ possible values for the degree of a vertex of the graph. However, a graph on $n$ vertices cannot have a vertex of degree $0$ **and** a vertex of degree $n-1$: if it has a vertex of degree $0$, the possible degrees of its vertices are $0,1,\ldots,n-2$, and if it has a vertex of degree $n-1$, the possible degrees of its vertices are $1,2,\ldots,n-1$. In each case there are just $n-1$ possibilities, and you can then apply the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 2):

You could assume that every vertex of $G$ has a unique degree and produce a contradiction. That is, since $G$ has order $n$ and every vertex degree is unique we know that the possible degree values must be $0,1,...,n-1$.

You could also use the pigeonhole principle since you know that $G$ either has a vertex of degree $n-1$ or it does not (two cases). With this information you can figure out the relationship between the number of vertices in $G$ and the set of all possible degrees for a vertex in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

My hint is the following:

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a simple graph such that $\#V\geq 2$.
Let $V:=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$.
Since $G$ is simple, $\deg(v_i)\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ for each $i$.
If $\deg(v_i)\neq\deg(v_j)$ for $i\neq j$, then $\{\deg(v_1),\dots,\deg(v_n)\}=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ must hold.
Then, there is $i$ such that $\deg(v_i)=0$.
Then, there is $j$ such that $\deg(v_j)=n-1$.
Since $n\geq 2$, $v_i\neq v_j$.
The vertex $v_j$ is adjacent to each vertex in $V\setminus\{v_j\}$.
And $v_i\in V\setminus\{v_j\}$.