# show that in a group of five people (where any two people are either friends or enemies)...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that in a group of five people (where any two people are either friends or enemies), there are not necessarily three mutual friends or three mutual enemies.

I am completely lost on this problem and have no idea where to even begin. Suggestions?

Comment: As many people have suggested, this is a problem that lends itself well to graph theory(and is equivalent to showing "the Ramsey number R(3,3) is greater than 5" if you haven't seen or heard of graph theory, I would look at the Wikipedia page in order to understand what types of things people are calling a "graph" as(in my experience) many people who haven't seen it have the wrong intuition of what a graph is(most non-math people think of functions on a Cartesian plane or bar graphs, but this is quite different).

Comment: See this question(ultimately the same type in graph theory) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958537/in-any-finite-graph-with-at-least-two-vertices-there-must-be-two-vertices-with

Answer (score 2):

You can find the right configuration using this reasoning:

- If one person $A$ in the group has (possibly more than) three friends $B,C,D$, then either some two of those three are also friends, completing a triangle of friends with $A$, or $B,C,D$ are a triangle of enemies. So we need each person to have at most two friends.
- Analogously we get that each person must have at most two enemies; because there are five people, this means that each person has exactly two friends and two enemies.
- Thinking of the people as nodes and their relationships as colored edges in a graph, as suggested in the other answers, we get that the edges of each color must form a union of cycles, but as we only have five nodes, this is only possible if they form two $5$-cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing there really is to do here is try things out.  In particular, you find that one arrangement that works is as follows:

$A \iff B \iff C \iff D \iff E \iff A$

That is, $A$ and $B$ are friends, $B$ and $C$ are friends, etc (depicted as a graph [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/RamseyTheory_K5_no_mono_K3.svg/210px-RamseyTheory_K5_no_mono_K3.svg.png)).  Any pair not mentioned are enemies.

If you want to be more systematic, note that if any person has either $3$ friends or $3$ enemies, the proof from the problem on $6$ people applies.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: All you need to do is consider all possible graphs on 5 vertices with less than or equal to half the possible edges present, and the first two vertices pre-defined, and then show there is such a graph such that in both the graph and the "opposite graph" (flip all edges, so in the opposite graph there is an edge if and only if it is not in the original graph), there is no triangle in either.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of this as a graph problem. There are 5 vertices (people). Any two people are either friends or enemies, so every pair of vertices is connected by a segment of line (an *edge*, in graph theory parlance) that represents either a friendship or an "enemyship". Of course, you can only label an edge one way or the other. Try a few such graphs until you see how to obtain a solution.